# scroll to top moves listview item to second position

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

As the question says, when I do either

```
listview.smoothScrollToPositionFromTop(position, 0);
```

or

```
listview.setSelectionFromTop(position, 0);
```

The item is scrolled to the second position in the list as opposed to the very top position. How do I get the item to scroll to the top position?

**UPDATE**

For a bit of context, the following would work

```
listview.smoothScrollToPositionFromTop(position+1, 0);
```

But I that would create tractability problems for me.

Comment: check that position = 0 instead of 1

Comment: Also just `smoothScrollToPosition(0)` works if you only want to go to the top position.

Answer (score 0):

Use listview.setSelection(int position) instead.
Also you can add OnScrollListener to your ListView for some more functionality.
I have implemented it in my application.